# Appium Android: I am seeing error message after running the following Appium script

Tags: android, compiler-errors, appium

After I run the following Appium JAVA code:

```
package com.appium;

io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.junit.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class NewTest {
    AndroidDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // creating a class object
        BasicTest testcases = new BasicTest();
          // call launch app method
          testcases.launchMilk();
          // call add name method
          testcases.addName();
    }

     //@Test
       public void launchMilk() throws InterruptedException, MalformedURLException
      {

       File app=new File("D:\\Radio\\Radio_1.5.1700010675.apk");



        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

      //Name of mobile web browser to automate. Should be an empty string if automating an app instead.
      capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");

      //which mobile OS to use: Android, iOS or FirefoxOS
      capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

      //Mobile OS version – in this case 4.4 since my device is running Android 4.4.2
      capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "4.4.2");

      //device name – since this is an actual device name is found using ADB
      capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "4d000614aef030c3");

      //the absolute local path to the APK
      capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());

      //Java package of the tested Android app
      capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.samsung.mdl.radio");

      // activity name for the Android activity you want to run from your package. This need to be preceded by a . (example: .MainActivity)
      capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".MainActivity");

      // constructor to initialize driver object
      driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        System.out.println("App Launched");
        //locating the 'I Agree' button
        WebElement StartUp = driver.findElementById("dialog_positive_button");
        //Clicking the I Agree button
        StartUp.click();
        System.out.println("I agree button clicked - wait for the screen to load");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("Intro Movie Playing");
        Thread.sleep(58000);
        System.out.println("App Launched");
        //List<WebElement> addContactButton = driver.findElementsByClassName("android.widget.ImageView");
        WebElement globalMenu = driver.findElementById("nav_drawer_icon");
        //System.out.println(addContactButton);
        globalMenu.click();


      }


        public void addName() throws InterruptedException {
             System.out.println("Test success");
                 // write all your tests here
             //driver.clickOnView(driver.getView(com.appium.R.id.dialog_positive_button));

           }
      }
```

The first step of the test runs successfully. The app gets launched. But after executing this line:

```
System.out.println("Intro Movie Playing");
    Thread.sleep(58000);
    System.out.println("App Launched");
```

The app does not locate the next element and the test fails:

I see the following error message in the console:

```
App Launched
I agree button clicked - wait for the screen to load
Intro Movie Playing
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: 
Command duration or timeout: 14 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:17:10'
System info: host: 'SCS02-LT-005', ip: '105.160.8.32', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities [{app=D:\Radio\Radio_1.5.1700010675.apk, appPackage=com.samsung.mdl.radio, networkConnectionEnabled=true, warnings={}, databaseEnabled=false, version=4.4.2, deviceName=4d000614aef030c3, platform=LINUX, appActivity=.MainActivity, desired={app=D:\Radio\Radio_1.5.1700010675.apk, appPackage=com.samsung.mdl.radio, appActivity=.MainActivity, browserName=, platformName=Android, version=4.4.2, deviceName=4d000614aef030c3}, platformVersion=4.4.2, webStorageEnabled=false, locationContextEnabled=false, browserName=, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=Android}]
Session ID: b3d9c76a-5924-4a92-a906-39889e77d37c
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=nav_drawer_icon}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:605)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:27)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:358)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:399)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElementById(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:47)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElementById(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElementById(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at com.appium.BasicTest.launchMilk(BasicTest.java:82)
    at com.appium.NewTest.main(NewTest.java:31)
```

Why am I seeing this error? Why does the code not detect the next element "nav_drawer_icon" in the test? This error prevents me from running more than one test in series. I am using UiAutomator to locate elements in the android app.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Pavan

Answer (score 0):

I think that you very close to the appium command timeout 60 sec. Please try to increase this timeout by using --command-timeout desired capability.

Comment: Hi Eugene, I set the command timeout to 90 seconds but I still see the same error. Appium does not allow me to progress from clicking one button element to the other.

Comment: Hi I suspect that something wrong with your last sleep because your second "App launched" is not printed. So the application hangs yet before the click.

Comment: Do you get this error after 90 seconds - sleep(58sec) is executed or not? How long is the movie? /// You can always set breakpoint on this line and debug it as JUnit test - you will see which line exactly causes the error.